# How do you actually get angular.js animation code from your javascript file to activate?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, animation

Down below where the app.controller starts, the console.log statement (Fourth line of angular.js code) renders an output to the console. Can anyone explain why the animation code does not get implemented? Does the hg-repeat directive allow for the elements inside of the div section to be repeated? Would be grateful for any kind of help. Thanks

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('TarasDeli', ['ngAnimate']);

DivInfo = [
{
    image: "SomeImage",
    time: "At /n" + "6:00 AM...",
    Happenstance: "Shop opens up /n" + "Chefs prepare",

},
{
    image: 'SomeImage',
    time: "At /n" + "11:30 AM.../n" + "...12:00 PM/n" + "...12:30 PM/n" + "...1:00 PM/n",
    Happenstance: "Students flood Deli /n" + "For Lunch",
},
{
    image: 'SomeImage',
    time: "At /n" + "4:00 AM/n",
    Happenstance: "Deli Closes",
}
    ];
```

Angular.js code apart of app.js

```
app.controller('FadeInOut', function(){

    this.mainDivs = DivInfo;

});
app.animation('.repeated-item', [function(){
        console.log('I work');

                return {

                    enter: function(element, done){
                        element.css('opacity', 0);
                        $(element).animate({
                            opacity: 1
                        }, done);

                    },

                    leave: function(element, done){
                        element.css('opacity', 1);
                        $(element).animate({
                            opacity: 0
                        }, done);

                    }
                };
}]);
```

Html

The angular.js expressions reflect the objects in the DivInfo array up above. The first image shows up in the view but the two other images are suppose to appear in the view with the enter method executing. And the angular.js code does not seem to render the last two images in the DivInfo array into the view. Also, I've downloaded the angular-animate module via node.js and put it as dependency. The scripts relied on are at the very bottom and are correct(double-checked).

```
<div id = 'Carousel-Inner' ng-controller = 'FadeInOut as DivCarousel'>
<div ng-repeat = 'mainDiv in DivCarousel.mainDivs' class = 'repeated-item'>
<img ng-src = "{{ mainDiv.image }}" /> 
<span>{{ mainDiv.time }}</span>
<p>{{ mainDiv.happenstance }}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

The scripts depended on

```
<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = '../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src = "../node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = '../app.js'></script>
<script src = '../Js/Deli.js'></script>
<script src = '../Js/MappingSys.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tricky to figure out what's wrong without a complete example, so I apologize if I'm misunderstanding this. Here's a demo I put together from your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/y2aosL35/1/

According to the docs, the animation events for ng-repeat are `enter`, `leave`, and `move`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

So adding an item to the DivInfo array will trigger the `enter` animation (I used  $timeout, to help make it clear in the demo)